# German characters not encoded correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I have the following function which encodes a string. I basically loop through the string and encode the characters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UrlEncode](@url nvarchar(MAX))
    RETURNS nvarchar(3072)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c nchar(1);
    DECLARE @count int = LEN(@url);
    DECLARE @i int = 1;
    DECLARE @urlReturn nvarchar(max) = '';

    WHILE (@i < = @count)
    BEGIN
        SET @c = SUBSTRING(@url, @i, 1);
    
        IF @c LIKE N'[A-Za-z0-9()''*\-._!~]' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ESCAPE N'\' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
        BEGIN
            SET @urlReturn = CONCAT(@urlReturn, @c);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @urlReturn = CONCAT(@urlReturn, '%',
                SUBSTRING(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(@c AS varbinary(MAX))), 3, 2),
                ISNULL(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(@c AS varbinary(MAX))), 5, 2), '00'), ''));
        END
    
        SET @i = @i +1;
     END

    RETURN @urlReturn;
END
```

When I do:

```
SELECT dbo.UrlEncode('ü')
```

I get: `%fc`

However encoded it should be `%C3%BC`.

What am I missing?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: `SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(N'ü' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))` will return `'0xfc00'`. You'll need to collate the input character using UTF8 first if you want to get the UTF8 encoding version of it.

Comment: Why should it be '%C3%BC'? SQL server doesn't convert data miraculously into something, resembling UTF-8 internal format.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning There is not `UTF8` version of the `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation. What is the nearest collation that might fit this purpose?

Comment: SQL Server treats `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` as UCS-2 encoding - unless you're using a Supplementary characters collation at which point it treats them as UTF-16 encoding. You could try `LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`. For example, `SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(CAST(N'ü' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)));` returns `'0xc3bc'` which you'd then have to rearrange in your function.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The function is still not encoding the `ü`. it might be because of this regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9()''*\-._!~]`

Comment: More importantly is, why are you using tsql to encode urls?

Comment: @IvanDebono there's no need for any kind of encoding. It's not just that SQL Server always supported Unicode through the `nvarchar` type, but the Latin1 codepage most developers use with `varchar` covers German explicitly.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support regex. Your `LIKE` pattern is working just fine. You're starting to experience the joys of variable length encodings like UTF-8 and UTF-16. e.g.: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1mNC3fSu)

Comment: @IvanDebono this is wrong too `UTF8 version of the Latin1_General_CI_AS. If you run `select * from sys.fn_helpcollations()
where name like 'latin%utf%'` you'll find 17 results like `German_PhoneBook_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8`, and if you run `like 'German%utf%'` you'll find 16 `German_Phonebook` variants. You don't need UFT8 to store Unicode though, nor will you gain anything in performance or space

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - UTF8 can be significantly more space efficient than UCS2 dependent on characters being stored.

Comment: @MartinSmith in text files yes. In SQL Server [not so much](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6168/impact-of-utf8-support-in-sql-server-2019/), given that Unicode compression is already available. As Aaron Bertrand concludes `I wouldn't say that there is an obvious situation where I would rush to switch to UTF-8 collations`. I rushed in a single database and the problems weren't worth it. Especially when the client language is natively Unicode (C#, Python, Java). I suspect the real benefit is that mentioned in the linked articles - allowing non-Unicode apps to work without modification

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unicode compression only applies if you are already using row or page compression and only to data stored in row

Answer (score 0):

I took a *completely* different direction here. Using a `WHILE` to achieve this will be awfully slow, and so too would a scalar function. I switched to a set based method, and designed a method for use in an iTVF instead.

This could very likely be streamlined, but it's just the direction I went as I wrote the solution:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UrlEncode](@url nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT LOWER(CONCAT('#',STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(B.VB,BGS.value,2),'#') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GS.value, BGS.value))) AS UrlReturn
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),@url COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)))V(url)
         CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(CONVERT(bigint,1), LEN(@url)) GS
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.url,GS.value,1)))SS(C)
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(varbinary(10),SS.C),2)))B(VB)
         CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(B.VB),2) BGS;
GO
```